# Ajax no MVC - Select

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou com um problema pra carregar os campos *select* no meu projeto.
Meus *forms* estão todos feitos com Razor e apenas os *select's(combobox)* eu carrego por ajax.

Problema: Quando inicio o formulário é iniciado o evento ajax para carregar os combos é disparado antes de eu obter os dados do meu *model*, cujo precisava para obter o *ID* pro campo ficar com o valor certo já selecionado.

Alguém saberia qual a solução para este caso? Como consigo iniciar ou obter o valor do meu model antes do evento ser disparado? Ah e Também acho q pode ser relevante o fato do meu form esta em uma PartialView.

```
@model EP.IdentityIsolation.Domain.Entities.Cadastro.Cliente
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Cliente";
}

<div class="card-body excluir-padding-top">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarCliente", "Cliente", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formCliente" }))
    {

    <div class="form-body">

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResponsavelLegal, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <select class="form-control input-validation-error" id="ResponsavelLegal_Id" name="ResponsavelLegal.Id">
                <option value="null">Nenhum</option>
            </select>
            <small>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResponsavelLegal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazaoSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazaoSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                <small>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazaoSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</small>
            </div>

    </div>

    }
</div>

@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

    getListaResponsavelLegal();
        function getListaResponsavelLegal() {
            var model = @Html.Raw((Model!= null && Model.ResponsavelLegal != 
            null) ? Model.ResponsavelLegal.Id : "");
            var ddlResponsavellegal = $("#ResponsavelLegal_Id");

            $.ajax({
                url: "DdlListaCliente",
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    // Remover todos existentes;
                    ddlResponsavellegal.empty();

                    // Criar campo vazio;
                    var opt = new Option("Nenhum", null);
                    ddlResponsavellegal.append(opt);

                    // Carrega lista do retorno
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var opt = new Option(data[i].NomeFantasia, data[i].Id);
                        ddlResponsavellegal.append(opt);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Mostre o seu código ou um exemplo minimo!?

Comment: Adicionei o codigo. @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Seu código faltou um chamada parecida com essa `$(document).ready(function() { .... });`, mas, internamente seu Script ta com problemas!

Comment: Que tipo de problema? tipo sei que preciso passar o valor do model no data do meu ajax, fora isso tem algum outro problema? Eu não domino javascript sei apenas o básico. Espero que possa me ajudar.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { getListaResponsavelLegal() });` tente assim retirando aquela linha sozinha `getListaResponsavelLegal()` e ve se funciona?

Comment: ainda assim quado esta executando a function meu model ainda esta null

Comment: é o que eu estou dizendo ... está errado seu código

Comment: Ops não sei se é relevante, mas o form em uso esta em uma PartialView.

Comment: ta, mas oq esta errado? @VirgilioNovic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou assumindo que a `Controller` está sendo chamada e os dados estão sendo recebidos da maneira correta. Se houver qual quer duvida quanto a isto, abra o `Developer Tools -> Network` e veja se a requisição retorna um codigo `200` e o `JSON` esperado no `Response`.

a única razão para um elemento não está acessível no Script, é o Script está sendo executado antes da renderização da pagina.

No seu caso em especifico, o mais prudente é mover o a `@RenderSection("scripts", false)` no seu arquivo de `Layout` para o final da `body`. Segue um exemplo.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        /* estilos aqui */
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
        /* scripts de blibiotecas aqui */
    </head>
    <body>
        /* corpo da pagina aqui */
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Uma segunda opção, é mover o `script` em questão para um arquivo `*.js` e adicionar o atributo `defer` a `tag script`

```
@section Scripts{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="*.js" defer>
}
```

Como ultima alteração, adicione o evento `readystatechange` ao `document` e espere que o `document` estaja `interactive` para executar o `getListaResponsavelLegal`.

```
var getListaResponsavelLegal = function () {
  /* faça a sua magina aqui */
}

document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (evt) {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    getListaResponsavelLegal()
  }
})
```

você pode alcançar um efeito semelhante com `jQuery` ao utilizar o [`jQuery.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
var getListaResponsavelLegal = function () {
  /* faça a sua magina aqui */
}

$(getListaResponsavelLegal)
```